# HTML and image conversion to pdf using jspdf

Tags: html, image, pdf, asp-classic, jspdf

Currently i work on a project in asp classic, jquery, and html

Recently, i sucessfully convert a html file to a pdf using "from-html.js", but i got one question wich is:

How can i insert some images in the pdf that i create ? i searched for a long time now and i don't find the way to do it.

I tried to use addhtml.js or addimage.js mixed up with my actual code but it doesn't work.
there's what i have currently done

```
<title>Recapitulatif Commande</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./examples/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.addimage.js"></script> 
<script src='./libs/Blob.js/Blob.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='./libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='./libs/png_support/zlib.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='./libs/png_support/png.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='./libs/deflate.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='jspdf.plugin.png_support.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<script language="JavaScript"> 

  $(document).ready( function(){

    var doc = new jsPDF();      

    var specialElementHandlers = 
    {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) 
        {
            return true;
        }
    };      

    $('#cmd').click(function () 
    {
        doc.fromHTML($('#mydiv').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170, 
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,          
        });
        doc.save('RecapCommande.pdf');
    });
});
</script>

<div id="mydiv">
    <h2><center>Bonjour voici un recap des notes</center></h2>
    <table id="table" width="100%" border="2px solid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="33%" align="center">date : </th>
                <th width="33%" align="center">montant : </th>
                <th width="33%" align="center">statut : </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>        
</div> <!-- /container -->
<table id="table14" width="100%" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="33%" align="center"><button id="cmd" align="center" >Imprimer votre commande</button></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

If you can help me, i would be so relieve, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will have to convert your table into a canvas then display it.First attach a hidden canvas to your div.Second copying your div into the hidden canvas.Third hide your table and unhide the canvas.fourth generate pdf.

```
<Script>
 //first
$("#table").append('<div  id="can" style="background-color:white" >
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="320" style="background-color:white"></canvas> </div>');
 //second
canvg('canvas', $("#table").html());
//third
var im = document.getElementById('canvas');
         im.style.display = 'block';
var create = document.getElementById('table');
         create.style.display = 'none';
//fourth..call function for pdf generation


</Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode your images to base64, and insert the data blob into the img src area... i.e.:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA......9k=" />
```

I know this is an old post, however I've been dealing with this issue today and have found that base64 images are the only way the HTML to PDF conversion can output them.